# Perrin Number - How to do it tailrecursive?

Tags: racket

In Racket:

```
; Number -> Number
; interp. Calculates the perrin sequence.

(check-expect (per 0) 3)
(check-expect (per 1) 0)
(check-expect (per 2) 2)
(check-expect (per 7) 7)
(check-expect (per 11) 22)

(define (per n)
  (cond
    [(= n 0) 3]
    [(= n 1) 0]
    [(= n 2) 2]
    [else (+ (per (- n 2)) (per (- n 3)))]
    )
  )
```

How to do this in tailrecursion to improve the complexity?
I cant come up with a solution. It should be doable with accumulators, but I cant figure it out, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to keep in variables the previous states, for this sequence in particular, there are three of them. Then, in each iteration we update the `n-3` and `n-2` values, and calculate the `n-1` value using the other previous values. This is what I mean:

```lisp
(define (perrin n)
  ; use a named `let` for simplicity, alternatively
  ; we could use a separate procedure as a helper
  (let loop ((a 3) (b 0) (c 2) (n n))
    (if (zero? n)
        a
        (loop b c (+ a b) (sub1 n)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `per` function could accept additional parameters, named `m`, `pn2` and `pn3`, the first one being the desired value for which you want to compute the sequence and the two other ones the results of computing the sequence for `n - 2` and `n - 3`.

Then, instead of calling `(per n)` and having it compute previous values recursively, you would start from n = 3 (other cases are easy) by calling `(aux-per 3 m 0 3)` and recurse with increasing values until `n` equal `m`.

You can easily update `pn2` and `pn3` while going up, since you already computed them. I didn't test it, so maybe you need additional auxiliary variables, but the approach is the same: define a step function from `n` to `n + 1` until you reach `m`, using function parameters as temporary storage.

Another approach is to memoize the non tail-recursive function.